# Retrieve text from external HTML/asp page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, telnet, hta

I am using an external asp page (On the company's server - not related to me beside the fact that I'm using it for my job).

The asp page has one query in it, I'm writing something in it and it gives me some information.

In the information there is a certain line with constant header (let's assume 'HEADER'), I want to build an HTA that pulls the line that contains 'HEADER' to my HTA and display only this line.

I think that this isn't possible without any server interaction, but I'm asking anyway.
Can someone think of a way doing it?

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: Ok, I made something with JavaScript, using Telnet, it isn't working for all sites, when I'll be at work I'll check it, but I think this will do the job. The code:   
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("telnet -fc:/telnetlog.txt www.google.com 80"); // This will save me the source file + minor junk!

 setTimeout("WshShell.SendKeys('GET / HTTP/1.0~~')",1000); // Enter the command it telnet

 </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made something with JavaScript, using Telnet.

It isn't working for all sites, when I'll be at work I'll check it, but I think this will do the job.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
   WshShell.Run("telnet -fc:/telnetlog.txt www.google.com 80"); // This will save me the source file + minor junk!
   setTimeout("WshShell.SendKeys('GET / HTTP/1.0~~')",1000); // Enter the command it telnet </script>
```

Thanks for the brainstorming,
Rotem

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Ajax request to pull data from that page. The javascript page needs to be on the same server as the page you want to pull data from because of cross site scripting prevention in most browsers. Here is a good place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Hi, as I said the page is external and I don't have access to it's server. I need something that won't have cross scripting issue.. If it matters I'm using HTA.

Comment: Then you would have to use a server side language which does not have a cross site scripting issue.

Comment: This is not an option for me because I don't have server to use. Maybe it is possible with telnet on port 80 to this URL? something like that?